# Django models inheritance

Tags: django, orm

I want to create base model for my submodels, for example: Car(Base) and Truck, Sportcart etc. And I want to bind them all using base class with another class, cuz I don't want to bind all of them separately with another class.
Example:
I have a user and I want to add to him cars (I will do it separately for each class, yes). And I want to get all of them using my base Car class.

Comment: Please do *not* use model inheritance, unless there is no other option. Relational databases are *not* effective with inheritance, and usually will result in slow queries, and ineffective ways to construct a query. Inheritance is a powerful tool in object-oriented programming, but it is actually one of the main problems when implementing an ORM to map the relational world to the OO world and vice versa.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Okay, but how can I solve my problem? Could u recommend some docs for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Mark your base model as abstract:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # Your fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then inherit from the abstract model:

```
class SportCar(Car):
    # Your fields
    pass
```

In this case Django will make migrations only for SportCar, because Car is an abstract model.